# Saving form data in the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Hello I am new in Django and I have created an available house posting form but I cannot store the entered data in the database. I used if form.is_valid and form.cleaned_data please I need help my code:

views.py

```
def public(request):
form = PublicationForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PublicationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        agency_name=form.cleaned_data['agency_name']
        city=form.cleaned_data['city']
        categories=form.cleaned_data['categories']
        status=form.cleaned_data['status']
        phone_number_1=form.cleaned_data['phone_number_1']
        phone_number_2=form.cleaned_data['phone_number_2']
        description=form.cleaned_data['description']
        image_one=form.cleaned_data['image_one']
        pub = Publication.objects.create(
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            agency_name=agency_name,
            city=city,
            categories=categories,
            status=status,
            phone_number_1=phone_number_1,
            phone_number_2=phone_number_2,
            description=description,
            image_one=image_one
        )
        pub.save()
    return HttpResponse("Publication réussie")
else:
    form = PublicationForm()

return render(request, 'pub/public.html', {'form':form})
```

This is my template views I used the django-crispy-form module

public.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data " class="form-block ">
                {% csrf_token %} {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        {{ form.first_name.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        {{ form.last_name.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.last_name.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        {{ form.agency_name.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.agency_name.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.agency_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        {{ form.city.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.city.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.city|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        {{ form.categories.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.categories.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.categories|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        {{ form.status.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.status.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.status|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        {{ form.phone_number_1.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.phone_number_1.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.phone_number_1|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        {{ form.phone_number_2.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.phone_number_2.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.phone_number_2|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        {{ form.description.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.description.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.description|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        {{ form.image_one.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.image_one.id_for_label }} "></label> {{ form.image_one|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit " class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block">Publier</button>
            </form>
```

It is a ModelForm In my form I have:

forms.py

```
class PublicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Publication
    fields = ["first_name",
        "last_name",
        "agency_name",
        "city",
        "categories",
        "status",
        "phone_number_1",
        "phone_number_2",
        "description",
        "image_one"
    ]
    widgets = {
        'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'agency_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'city': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Choisir une ville'} ),
        'categories': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Choisir une catégorie'}),
        'status': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Choisir un statut'}),
        'phone_number_1': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'phone_number_2': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'description': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'image_one': FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a model form, it is a form which connects to your model.
What you are doing is taking out all of the user input and trying to create a object with it.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

In my example you would just save the form input which connects to the model.

---

EDIT:
Added the Message to `views.py`
The redirect takes the input of the name of path put in `urls.py`

Messages links:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/

Redirect link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

```
#Views.py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

    def public(request):
        form = PublicationForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = PublicationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Your password was updated successfully!')
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = PublicationForm()
        
        return render(request, 'pub/public.html', {'form':form})
```

---

```
#template
{% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Now I would like to be redirected to the same page with a message ... How do I do this ??

Comment: Added messages and redirect into the answer.

@Da-cruzWilfried

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
def public(request):
    form = PublicationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():    
        pub = form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Publication réussie")

    return render(request, 'pub/public.html', {'form':form})
```